# Typescript: Can I derive an enum for capitalized members?

Tags: typescript, enums

We're building a service that works roughly like this:

1. Take an input, for example `{titleDe: 'Lorem', titleFr: 'Ipsum'};`
2. Return all suffixed properties for a target language ('de' for example)
3. Output: `{title: 'Lorem'}`

We do use this enum to check which language is requested:

```
export enum Language {
  DE = 'de',
  IT = 'it',
  FR = 'fr',
  EN = 'en',
}
```

Then we have another enum to check the suffix we need to get the requested language:

```
export enum LanguageSuffix {
  DE = 'De',
  IT = 'It',
  FR = 'Fr',
  EN = 'En',
}
```

I don't like having two enums for this - it's the same but capitalized. I tried something like this:

```
enum LanguageSuffix { DE = Capitalize<Language> }
```

But that obviously doesn't work because one is a value, the other a type. Is there any proper way to do this with one "base enum" and a second derived one?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8nvW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes it's the desired output but not really readable.. see zenly & Igor Topolski's answer below, I think it's a bit better.
Still thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it make sense to maintain two enums at all? Even if you take first enum and capitalise in the second one, you're still maintaining two of them.

Wouldn't it make more sense to create a formatter that would format the raw value for you e.g.

```
export enum Language {
  DE = 'de',
  IT = 'it',
  FR = 'fr',
  EN = 'en',
}

export const LanguageFormatter = <T extends Language>(base: T) => `${base.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${base.substring(1)}` as Capitalize<T>;
```

```
console.log(LanguageFormatter(Language.DE)); // should return 'De'
```

Comment: Of course, having only one would be best!
Your `LanguageFormatter` function isn't really as typesafe as I'd like - it's return value is `string` (which is not wrong but not as precise as I'd like it).

Comment: This might be hard to achieve then as TypeScript string enums can only be initialised with a constant value.

Comment: @sandrooco Fixed: https://tsplay.dev/Wvx6RN